# F# build error: "No compiled representation for provided namespace"

Tags: f#, fable-f#, paket

Has anyone run into this error message before? Google found it for me in the source code (https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/tast.fs), but I haven't the slightest idea what is causing it.

This started happening when I tried to upgrade my library project from .NET 5 to .NET 6, so the real answer to my question may be an explanation of what I did wrong there. All I did was the following:

1. In the fsproj, changed "TargetFramework" from "net5.0" to "net6.0"
2. In my paket.dependencies file, changed "framework" from "net5.0" to "net6.0". (I've also tried commenting out the "framework" line.)

Then after running "paket update" and "dotnet build" I get the obscure error. ("error FS0192 : internal error : No compiled representation for provided namespace")

**UPDATE: After some laborious code commenting/uncommenting, etc., I believe I've narrowed this down to my code's use of the Fable.RegexProvider assembly. (I use the SafeRegex component.) RegexProvider hasn't been updated in a couple years. I'll alert the folks over there to this issue, and I'll post an update here if/when I learn anything. (In case anybody else runs into this.)**

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? What version?

Comment: Hi @JimFoye, I'm using VS Code. Per my update above, though, it looks like the culprit is the Fable.RegexProvider library.

Comment: Maybe try to switch to https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Text.RegexProvider/ ?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this, here is the solution (which is the solution @CaringDev recommended above, though it only works for Fable 3.7.18 and after):

When I raised this issue on the Fable.RegexProvider github (see thread here: https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable.RegexProvider/issues/9), the initial thought was to try a .NET 6 build of Fable.RegexProvider. But then [Alfonso Garcia-Caro](https://github.com/alfonsogarciacaro) realized that subsequent improvements to Fable may have obviated the need for SafeRegex.

He ultimately needed to tweak something in Fable, but as of version 3.7.18, the Fable transpiler supports the use of FSharp.Text.RegexProvider, such that Fable.RegexProvider is now unnecessary.